# Python Mysql stuck on cursor.execute()

Tags: python, mysql

I am executing sql select statement with python and sometimes execution get stuck. I can see on mysql server that query is in state "Writing to net" after some time on mysql server query disappears, but python is still on execution. What can be wrong? Can it be problems with DB or python configuration?

```
mydb = pyodbc.connect(driver = f_driver,server = f_server,uid = f_uid,pwd = f_pwd,database = f_database,port = f_port,trusted_connection = f_trusted_connection)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
startTime = datetime.datetime.today()

f_query =
    """
    SELECT * 
    FROM sessions_detail
    where date = '""" + str(date) + """'"""

mycursor.execute(f_query)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: Maybe provide a part of your code and your stacktrace.

Comment: mydb = pyodbc.connect(
   driver = f_driver,
   server = f_server,
   uid = f_uid,
   pwd = f_pwd,
   database = f_database,
   port = f_port,
   trusted_connection = f_trusted_connection
  )
  
  mycursor = mydb.cursor()

  print("Starting...")
  startTime = datetime.datetime.today()
  mycursor.execute(f_query)
  
  myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
 
  mycursor.close()
  mydb.close()

Comment: That's not helping at all. Change your initial question with your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: add your sql query to your question

Comment: I am new hear so sorry. Code is very simple and if query do net get stuck in write to net state everything works, but if it is longer than 10s in this state execution is not finished. it looks like python is waiting for reseult set, but mysql server have closed connection.

Comment: Since this issue happening "sometimes", You better check your PyMySQL requirements are intact. You better check your Linux kernel version is up to date. Refer https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/#requirements and worth going through https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/mysql-and-percona-server/43419-intermittent-random-mysql-queries-stuck-on-writing-to-net-state .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with our database kernel. after update everything is working fine.